# How to return the array full of mail content?

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

I am new with promises and i am trying to return the body[] after the promise of gmail has finished.

```
app.get('/',  (req, res) => {
    var body =[];

    if (!authed) {
        // Generate an OAuth URL and redirect there
        const url = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
            access_type: 'offline',
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
        });
        console.log(url)
        res.redirect(url);
    } else {
        
        // getmail(), function(stories) {
        //     console.log(stories);
        // };
        getmail().then(function(gmail) {
            console.log("mails"); // "Success"

            console.log(gmail); // "Success"
          }, function(value) {
          });
}
getmail = async function(){
    const gmail = await google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: oAuth2Client });
    const body = [];

    await  gmail.users.messages.list({
        'userId': 'me',
        'labelIds': 'UNREAD',
        'maxResults': 10
      }, (err, res) => {
            if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
            const  msgs= res.data.messages;
            if (msgs.length == 0) {
                console.log('No labels found.');

            } else {
                console.log('Messages:');
                the_format = 'full';
                for (var i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                  var msg = msgs[i];
                   body[i] =  gmail.users.messages.get({
                    auth: oAuth2Client,
                    userId: 'me',
                    id: msg.id,
                    payload:msg.payload,
                    format: the_format,
                  }, function(err, response) {
                    if (err) {
                       console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
                       return;
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("Returning")
                        return response.data.payload.parts[0].body.data;
                    }
                  });
                  console.log(body[i])

                }  
            }
        });
        console.log(body);
        return Promise.all(body,gmail);
    }
})
```

I am sure i am doing something wrong i just cant figure out what, the mails are loaded but the function never waits for the body to fill returns it empty. i also tried body.push(response.data.payload.parts[0].body.data;) and still returns it empty

Comment: Not sure where exactly your problem lies. Can you implement logs to determine at what point the code works differently from what you expect?

Comment: i played with the logs,  console.log(gmail), and     console.log(body); are empty, it seems doesn't wait it and then it prints it again inside the promise          console.log(body[i]) and it filled up